# Organizing HTML with jQuery: How to slice from an array and organize 3 rows (imgs.lenght/3) of "items" where each item has

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create 3 carousels that split the images between three rows.

This is my current HTML:

`<img>` x 6 for example.

```
<div class="car-cont">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

This should be the result:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">


        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img-1.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="animg">
                <img class="alignnone" src="img.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and this is my jQuery part (I explained more in each code part please review carefully):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Adds this "animg" class in a div outside every img tag
    jQuery( ".car-cont > img" ).wrap( "<div class='animg'></div>" );

    // Calculates how many "items" should be in a row. for example if there are 6 items - there should be 2 items in a row of one carusele
    var imgNums = jQuery('.animg').length;
    imgNums = imgNums/3;

    // Organize to Items - for every 7 images add the class item. 
    var theItems = jQuery(".car-cont > .animg");
    for(var i = 0; i < theItems.length; i+=7) {
        theItems.slice(i, i+7).wrapAll("<div class='item'></div>");
    }

    // Organize to Carusel containers (items) - split the items so there will be 2 items pear each row of carusel 
    var theCarusels = jQuery(".car-cont > .item");
    for (var c=0; c < theCarusels.length; c+=imgNums ) {
        theCarusels.slice(c, c+imgNums).wrap("<div class='carousel slide' id='myCarousel'><div class='carousel-inner'></div></div>");
    } 

    jQuery('.carousel-inner > .item:first').addClass('active');

    jQuery('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    });

});
```

The problem starts in the loop after the `var theCarusels` statement.

I get:

[image]

and using `.wrapAll` gives this result:

[image]

Comment: In a previous edit there were more images in the original html that where to be reformatted into the final html.  There appears to be now just 6.  Are the various carousels now just a duplication of each other?

Comment: There can be more than 6 I just thought the best easiest example can be made with 6.

Comment: @JonSG so if there where 9 images - imgNum will be 3 and there will be 3 "items" in each "carousel-inner" div. If there where 12 images, imgNum will be 4 and there will be 4 "items" in each "carousel-inner" div. Ect.. ;)
I just cant get this class=items split right.

Comment: What should happen if the number of images is not a multiple of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved using this part:

```
// Organize to Carusel containers
var theCarusels = jQuery(".car-cont > .item");
var carCount = theCarusels.length; 
carCount = carCount/3;
for (var c=0; c < theCarusels.length; c+=carCount ) {
    theCarusels.slice(c, c+carCount).wrapAll("<div class='carousel slide' id='myCarousel'><div class='carousel-inner'></div></div>");
}
```

I used the wrong variable in the for loop. 
Instead of using it for the items I calculated it for the images.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a slightly different approach and relies on a pair of **reduce()** methods.  One to determine how to split up the images and reformat them into the required carousels, the second to split the individual carousel image arrays into a collection of images that I have called *slides*

```js
// ==========================
// Generate a reducer based on imagesPerSlide
// ==========================
function getSlideReducer(imagesPerSlide){

  // ==========================
  // Given an array of "images" return "items"
  // appended to the accumulator (carousel-inner) 
  // ==========================
  return function(acc, item, index, arr){
    var $slide = $("<div class=\"item\" />");

    arr
      .splice(0, imagesPerSlide)
      .forEach(function(item){
        $("<div class=\"animg\" />").append(item).appendTo($slide);
      });

    $slide.appendTo(acc);

    return acc;
  };
  // ==========================

}
// ==========================

// ==========================
// Generate a reducer based on the number of images and expected carousels
// also needed is a child reducer to process the individual slides in each
// carousel
// ==========================
function getCarouselReducer(imagesPerCarouselFloor, slideReducer){

  // ==========================
  // Given an array of images, slice up the array to distribute images
  // evenly to the required number of carousels.
  // once the slice of images is found for the current carousel, pass them
  // to a child reducer for futher processing.
  // ==========================
  return function(acc, item, index, arr){
    var $carousel = $("<div class=\"carousel slide\" />");

    var grab = (arr.length % imagesPerCarouselFloor === 0) ?
      imagesPerCarouselFloor : imagesPerCarouselFloor + 1;

    arr
      .splice(0, grab)
      .reduce(slideReducer, $("<div class=\"carousel-inner\" />"))
      .appendTo($carousel);

    $carousel.appendTo(acc);

    return acc;
  };
  // ==========================

}
// ==========================

// ==========================
// find our target container with child images and
// using a pair of reducers replace the child images
// with a set of carousels
// ==========================
(function($, targetContainer, carouselCount, imagesPerSlide){
  var $targetContainer = $(targetContainer);
  var images = Array.from($targetContainer.find("img"));
  var imagesPerCarouselFloor = Math.floor(images.length / carouselCount);

  var slideReducer = getSlideReducer(imagesPerSlide);
  var carouselReducer = getCarouselReducer(imagesPerCarouselFloor, slideReducer);

  images.reduce(carouselReducer, $targetContainer);

  $targetContainer.find(".item:first-child").addClass("active");
  $targetContainer.find('.carousel').carousel({interval: 3000});
}(jQuery, ".car-cont", 3, 5));
// ==========================
```

```css
.animg { float: left; padding: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="car-cont">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=0">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=1">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=2">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=3">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=6">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=7">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=8">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=9">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=0">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=1">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=2">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=3">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=6">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=7">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=8">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=9">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=0">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=1">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=2">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=3">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=4">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/50?image=5">
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```